# Java shared Property File: Windows + Unix (generic)

Tags: java, windows, unix

So, in my departement, we got an Java application (running on Unix) which can be parametrised by an .property File. Inside this File, there are few refrences to other files (e.g. Log file path). Now, we need to use the same application on windows platforms. Everything works fine, until it should all be generic. So, we don‘t want to change anything except the .property file to make it run on both systems generic.
But I don‘t really know how to handle this. On Unix, I need like environment variavles on unix but I know, Java can not resolve environment variables automatically. In windows its like the same. 
How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Where is the log file located?  If it’s relative to, say, the home directory, you can simply specify a relative path in your properties and change the code to always resolve it against the home directory at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property for each OS and then read accordingly on code

```
# properties file
my.prop.nix=/some/unix/path
my.prop.win=c:\some \window$\path
```

Read OS on java with

```
String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Thank you @Luis Munoz, this never came uo to me! Now I can handle different OS inside code!